# SOLVED Could not create task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'

Tags: java, android, gradle

I have been developing an android app using Kotlin in Android studio.

Here is my error when trying to sync gradle files:

```
A build operation failed.
    Could not create task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.
Could not create task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.
Cannot use @TaskAction annotation on method AbstractKotlinCompile.execute() because interface org.gradle.api.tasks.incremental.IncrementalTaskInputs is not a valid parameter to an action method.
```

`./gradlew build --stacktrace > logs.txt 2>logErrors.txt`

Log errors:

**[https://pastebin.com/SjQDgVex]**

**app/build.gradle.kts**

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
}

android {
    namespace = "com.example.wherehouse"
    compileSdk = 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.wherehouse"
        minSdk = 24
        targetSdk = 33
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        getByName("release") {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "11"
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0")
    implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1")
    implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0")
    implementation("androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4")
    implementation("com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:4.2.0")
    implementation("com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0")
    implementation("com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.5.21")
}
```

**root/build.gradle.kts**

A Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

```
buildscript {
    val agp_version by extra("7.4.2")
    val agp_version1 by extra("8.0.0")
    val agp_version2 by extra("8.1.3")
    val agp_version3 by extra(agp_version2)

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.21")
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:$agp_version2")
    }
}
```

[Gradle plugin version and Gradle version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJPAD.png)

Attempted solutions:
invalidating caches, restarting, project rebuilding etc..

Updating gradle version, downgrading gradle version
updating java jdk, downgrading java jdk

altering compileOptions do different java versions.

I end up in a circle, coming back to the same problem after trying to fix new ones.

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION:
*I was able to fix this by altering my Java version to 11 and using AGP Android upgrade assistant
using these dependencies:

```
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.6.21")
        // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.android.tools.build/gradle
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.1.0")

    }
```

These plugin versions:

and this in gradle-wrapper.properties:
`distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.4-bin.zip`

Then I went to Tools > AGP Upgrade Assistant and pressed run, then it sorted itself out!
[Docs for this tool](https://developer.android.com/build/releases/gradle-plugin)
So take my versions with a pinch of salt.

*